# Ruby: PUT Request with JSON body?

Tags: ruby, json, httprequest, put

I need to create an **HTTP PUT request** using ruby.

The request has a **JSON body**

I was able to generate the JSON body using:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
jsonbody = JSON.generate["message"=>"test","user"=>"user1"]
```

I need to send this PUT request to the url:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = URI.parse('http://www.data.com?access_token=123')
```

Can someone please tell me how I can do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [restclient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) (**gem install rest-client**) like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

jdata = JSON.generate(["test"])
RestClient.put 'http://localhost:4567/users/123', jdata, {:content_type => :json}
```

against the following [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) service:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

put '/users/:id' do |n|
  data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  "Got #{data} for user #{n}"
end
```

works on my computer.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is with `Net::HTTP`:

```
require 'net/http'
http = Net::HTTP.new('www.data.com')
response = http.request_put('/?access_token=123', jsonbody)
```

Comment: i receive the error: 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1060:in `request': undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:996:in `request_put'
from json.rb:23