# Ruby: HTTP Put method

Tags: ruby, curl, put

I am attempting to update the 'ip' parameter in a json object in an API.

I have the following case:

```
when "put"
  uri = URI.parse("http://#{ip}:#{port}/api/v1/address_data/1.json")
  jobj = Hash.new
  jobj['ip'] = "1.1.1.1"
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.hostname, uri.port)
  response = http.send_request('PUT', '/api/v1/address_data/1.json', data = jobj.to_s)
end
```

This does not work, but this does:

```
curl -X PUT http://ip:port/api/v1/address_data/1.json -d "ip=1.1.1.1"
```

How do I more accurately translate the curl into a Put request in Ruby? I have tried several methods I've found through google searching, but none of them have had successful results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: PUT Request with JSON body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762541/ruby-put-request-with-json-body)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

- You're not sending JSON in the Ruby example, it's a string representation of a Ruby hash which isn't the same. You need the [JSON module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) or similar.
- In the Ruby code you're attempting to send a JSON object (which would look like `{"ip":"1.1.1.1"}` and in the curl example you're sending it in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format, so they're currently not equivalent.
- Also I'd look at the type of data the server expects from your requests: both Ruby and curl send a request header of `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default, and you're expecting to send JSON. This is why the curl example works: the data format you're using and the header matches. Note the `.json` in the URL shouldn't really make any difference; the header takes precedence.
- Your call to `send_request` has you picking out the `data` parameter as a Python-style keyword argument. Ruby doesn't do that: what you're actually doing there is assigning a local variable in-line with the call.

So try something like this:

```
require 'json' # put this at the top of the file

uri = URI.parse("http://#{ip}:#{port}/api/v1/address_data/1.json")
jobj = {"ip" => "1.1.1.1"}
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.hostname, uri.port)
response = http.send_request('PUT', uri.path, JSON.dump(jobj),
  {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

And just a friendly reminder, saying something "doesn't work" doesn't usually give enough information to people that might answer your question: try and remember to paste in error messages, stack traces, and things like that :)

Comment: Thanks Dan! I was requiring json, but I didn't really fully understand the difference in the data = part. The JSON.dump part made total sense. Works like a charm.